# Join Inline function and temporary table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I want to join Temporary table and Inline Function.
Here is temporary table 
[image]

and in fnproduct() there is also variantSKU so I want to join this two
here is my code

```
select * from dbo.fnproduct() join ##dq_IsUnique on 
dbo.fnproduct().VariantSKU= ##dq_IsUnique.VariantSKU
```

But I am getting error

```
Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate 
"dbo.fnproduct", or the name is ambiguous.
```

help me to solve  it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to specify or call the function again in joining logic

```
select * 
from dbo.fnproduct() t
join ##dq_IsUnique on t.VariantSKU = ##dq_IsUnique.VariantSKU
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but please try like this. Use Cross Apply.

```
SELECT * FROM ##dq_IsUnique U
CROSS APPLY
(
    select * from dbo.fnproduct()  
    WHERE VariantSKU = U.VariantSKU
)p
```

Comment: What you say is true. but I want to use join because Cross join is heavy and
I will get my answer only if there is join.